# Dynamics table in Angular from two array of object

Tags: angular, html-table

I'm making a dynamic table (from scratch), which build itself from two array of objects, "columns" and "rows".

Each column object have a property, "id", which I want to use in order to select the good property to display on each column (because I don't know the number of columns that will be in the row).

component html:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor='let key of columns'>
              {{ key.label }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let row of rows'>
            <td></td> <!-- I don't know how to do from here -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sample data:

Columns :

```js
this.columns = [{
        id: "id",
        label: "Id"
      },
      {
        id: "name",
        label: "Name"
      },
      {
        id: "postal_code",
        label: "Postal Code"
      }
    ];
```

Rows:

```js
this.rows = [{
            id: 120000,
            name: 'Test0',
            postal_code: 44000
          },
          {
            id: 120001,
            useless_column: true,
            postal_code: 44000
          },
          {
            name: 'Test2',
            id: 120002,
            postal_code: 44000
          },
          {
            name: 'Test3',
            id: 120003
          },
        ]
```

The result should looks something like the following :

```
|  Id  | Name |Postal Code|
|------|------|-----------|
|120000|Test0 |      44000|
|120001|      |      44000|
|120002|Test2 |      44000|
|120003|Test3 |           |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to loops on columns inside the row loop and then access specific row key something like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor='let key of columns'>
              {{ key.label }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let row of rows'>
            <td *ngFor='let key of columns'>
            {{row[key.id]}}
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l1k55w)